# How I can display Image on mouseover event on asp:linkButton

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am using asp.net framework 3.5 and c# 2.0. I am able to bind data in to gridview.
Actually I want to display Image on mouseover event on asp:linkButton, which is used in grid view

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvTemplate" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" ShowFooter="True" Width="100%"
    OnRowCommand="gvTemplate_RowCommand" OnRowDataBound="RowDataBound" OnPageIndexChanging="gvTemplate_PageIndexChanging">
                                                <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderText="Sr. No">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Template Name" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lBtTempID" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"tempName") %>'
                    CommandName='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"tempID") %>' CommandArgument="tempID" onmouseover="javascript:showImage(this.id)"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderText="Template Type">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lbltempType" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"tempType") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: What's there in your showImage function, can you past it

Comment: wheres your showImage() function

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jquery it would be like this

```
    $('.lBtTempClass').mouseover(function() {
///  Do your code
    });
```

you should add a css class to link button

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lBtTempID" CssClass="lBtTempClass" runat="server" >
```